# Animating recursive backtracking algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm stuck on trying to animate a color change in a back tracking algorithm as it happens in the recursive function. As of now when I run the function, it updates the colors only at the end of the function.

I've read several articles online and I think this problem happens because it is being run synchronously while I need to run it asynchronously.

I've tried a setTimeout inside the function, however it just causes the browser to wait the set amount of time, then updates everything at the same time.

What I have now is the Queens being set in valid positions, and then when I find out that those positions are no longer valid, I change them back to their original color using myFunction.

I'm a little new to javascript so any insight would be helpful, thanks.

```
  function myFunction(name, color) {
        document.getElementById(name).style.background = color;
    }

    function NQueen(col) {
        if (col == n) {
            return true;
        }
        // Checks if given move is valid for all positions in the column
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            let square = "square" + i + col;
            if (isValid(i,col)) {
                board[i][col] = 1;
                let originalColor = document.getElementById(square).style.background;
                //setTimeout(function() {myFunction(square, color)}, 2000);
                myFunction(square, "rgb(255,0,0)");

                if (NQueen(col+1)) {    
                    return true;
                }

                myFunction(square, originalColor);  
                board[i][col] = 0;

            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

**EDIT**

I think I figured out a workaround, I made objects that has the square name and it's color to change into and put them into an array. I then made a recursive function to change the background and updating it using setTimeout. It's a little weird but it works

```
    function myFunction(num) {
        var name = arr[num].square;
        var color = arr[num].color;
        document.getElementById(name).style.background = color;
        if (num < arr.length) setTimeout(function(){myFunction(num+1)}, 1000);

    }
```